# Django in a Subdirectory using fcgi

Tags: django, apache, subdirectory, fastcgi, bluehost

I'm trying to avoid having to somehow add a context_processor to add the base url of my project to every url I use in all of my templates.

My django project is nestled under a subdirectory(lets call it foo) and a lot of my urls in my templates are similar to this:

```
<a href='/somepath'>whatever</a>
```

This works fine for a project that is hosted on the root of a domain, but in this case since I am under the subdirectory foo the url would actually point to
www.example.com/somepath

The interesting thing is that the Admin site works fine. All of its url's are pointing to 
foo/admin/...

I suspect I'm not searching for the correct terms to find the answer to this.

.htaccess

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foo.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

.fcgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

# Current Path
cwd = os.path.join( os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) ) )

# Activate current virtualenv
activate_this = os.path.join( cwd, 'bin', 'activate_this.py' )
execfile( activate_this, dict( __file__ = activate_this ) )

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert( 0, os.path.join( cwd, 'foo' ) )

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'foo.settings'
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Most url's I can use the {% url %} and FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME to have work correctly, but for the url's that I do not have an entry in urls.py to reverse() with, I'm not sure if I should just use the FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME variable in the template for them or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem. Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it will do for now.

1. Ensure you have FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME set to whatever your sub directory is
2. Created context_processors.py inside same directory as settings.py
3. Added context_processors.url_prefix to settings.py under CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
4. Anywhere in a template that you cannot use the {% url %} tag, just prepend with {{ URL_PREFIX }}

context_processors.py

```
from django.conf import settings # import the settings file

def url_prefix(request):
    # return the value you want as a dictionnary. you may add multiple values in there.
    return {'URL_PREFIX': settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME}
```

settings.py

```
CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...,
    'context_processors.url_prefix',
)
```